# Swift Animation Issue

Tags: ios, animation, swift

I am creating a very basic Swift Function that will animate an UIView to the center of the screen, have it appear and double in size and then lastly shrink back to it's original size while returning to it's original position.  Here is the code:

```
func toTheCorner(view: UIView, delay: Double)
{
    // record original position
    let originalCenter = view.center
    // record original bounds
    let b = view.bounds

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.1, delay: delay, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.2, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: .CurveEaseOut, animations: {

        // move view to center of screen
        view.center.x = self.view.bounds.width/2
        view.center.y = self.view.bounds.height/2


        }, completion: nil)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.9, delay: delay + 0.1, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 10, options: .CurveEaseOut, animations: {

        // Fade image in
        view.alpha = 1.0

        // Increase size
        view.bounds.size.height = b.height + b.height/2
        view.bounds.size.width = b.width + b.width/2

        }, completion: nil)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.7, delay: delay + 1.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 10, options: .CurveEaseOut, animations: {

        // Shrink to original size
        view.bounds.size.height = b.height
        view.bounds.size.width = b.width

        // Move to original position
        view.center = originalCenter


    }, completion: nil)

}
```

The line that is creating an issue is:

```
view.center = originalCenter
```

Without this line the function executes as expected.  The View comes up in the center of the screen and doubles then shrinks.  But, as soon as I enter "view.center = originalCenter" the view appears in exactly opposite its original spot across the center of the screen instead of the middle and then moves to it's original point.

How is this line affecting the first 2 animations? This seems like this should work, and be very simple...

Thank you!
Ben

Comment: Odd. println the value of originalCenter after it's defined, and again where `view.center = originalCenter` is. What are the values?

Comment: They are the center value of the original position... Same thing happens if i just plug in the numbers from the original center.

Comment: I copied/pasted your code and everything worked correctly.  Maybe you can setup a demo project that exhibits the problem for us to look at?  Perhaps there's something else going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use completion block for this;

```
func toTheCorner(view: UIView, delay: Double)
{
    // record original position
    let originalCenter = view.center
    // record original bounds
    let b = view.bounds

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.1, delay: delay, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.2, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: .CurveEaseOut, animations: {

        // move view to center of screen
        view.center.x = self.view.bounds.width/2
        view.center.y = self.view.bounds.height/2

        }, completion: { finished in 
   UIView.animateWithDuration(0.9, delay: delay + 0.1, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 10, options: .CurveEaseOut, animations: {

        // Fade image in
        view.alpha = 1.0

        // Increase size
        view.bounds.size.height = b.height + b.height/2
        view.bounds.size.width = b.width + b.width/2

        }, completion: { finished in 
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.7, delay: delay + 1.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 10, options: .CurveEaseOut, animations: {

        // Shrink to original size
        view.bounds.size.height = b.height
        view.bounds.size.width = b.width

        // Move to original position
        view.center = originalCenter
    }, completion: nil)})
    })
}
```

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think you are using objective-C syntax for the closures.  I'm trying to implement this by figuring out the correct swift syntax.

Comment: Looks like the block signatures are the only syntax problem, so I've dropped in with an edit for those.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of chaining them in their completion closures, you can also use the [UIView.animateKeyframes](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622552-animatekeyframes) method. See below, where "subview" is the view you want to animate, and "originalPoint" is the view's starting CGPoint.

```
    let duration1 = 0.1
    let duration2 = 0.9
    let duration3 = 0.7

    let animations = {
        UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: delay, relativeDuration: duration1) {
            subview.center = self.view.center
        }
        UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: delay + duration1, relativeDuration: duration2) {    
            subview.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.5, y: 1.5)
        }
        UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: delay + duration1 + duration2, relativeDuration: duration3) {
            subview.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0, y: 1.0)
            subview.center = originalPoint
        }
    }
    let completion = { (done: Bool) -> () in
        print("done")
    }
    UIView.animateKeyframes(
        withDuration: [duration1, duration2, duration3].reduce(0, +),
        delay: delay,
        options: [],
        animations: animations,
        completion: completion)
```

This method takes a closure that can contain multiple [UIView.addKeyframes](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622554-addkeyframe) functions. See also this simpler example for animating thru multiple colors [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31274802/1751073).