# swift animation does not go through all keyframes

Tags: swift, animation, uicolor

I want to go through red -> green -> blue, but when I add 3 colors, it just go through the last two colors:

```
    var duration = 6.0

    UIView.animateKeyframesWithDuration(duration, delay: 1.0, options: UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptions.Repeat | UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptions.Autoreverse, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.colorTransition.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        self.colorTransition.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        self.colorTransition.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

    }, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to call [`addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime:relativeDuration:animations:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622554-addkeyframe) for each of the three transitions, specifying when they start (as percentages of the overall duration) and for how long (again, as percentages).

For example:

```
UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: duration, delay: 2, options: [.repeat, .autoreverse], animations: {
    UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0, relativeDuration: 0.33) {
        self.colorTransition.backgroundColor = .red
    }
    UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.33, relativeDuration: 0.33) {
        self.colorTransition.backgroundColor = .green
    }
    UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.66, relativeDuration: 0.34) {
        self.colorTransition.backgroundColor = .blue
    }
})
```

So, even though the total duration is 2 seconds, the relative start and duration values are percentages, values between 0 and 1.